# Core Data returning null properties in 64 bit devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, 64-bit

I'm gonna do my best to explain the situation, currently my app is working great for 32 bits devices, it requests objects from Core Data, I get objects with fault data (which is ok), then I send the object up to the point where I need to access their data, and for 32-bits devices this is working just fine. Last week I had to add 64 bit support and then some information was missing, when I was looking where was the problem I saw that on 64-bits devices when trying to access to a property it reads it as null.

I'm sure on 64-bits I'm receiving data I forced not to fault the properties of the object and I can see the information like this:

```
<SMNEntityRef: 0x1780bb960> (entity: SMNEntityRef; id: 0xd0000000000c0016 <x-coredata://418E114E-E5C7-4DEE-9D5F-1DCD8FCF4F25/SMNEntityRef/p3> ; data: {
    name = somename;
    id = "someId";
    url = "someURL";
})
```

Then when the object is when is going to be used is fault again but can't read its properties, when trying to print out is Id I get this:

```
2015-02-11 09:51:26.334 MyAppUniversal[1996:797407] entityID: (null)
```

And on 32 bits devices, I can read perfectly the data.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: How do you save the to CoreData? which type is entityID that you are get as null on 64bit?

Comment: Hello @IAmDav, the app request info to the API, then parses it, creates NSManagedObjects then saves it using its context:

[context save:&error];

 And the entityID is a string.

Comment: What types of fields your NSManagedObject contains? If you are using any integers I would suggest to make NSInteger, as it is 32bit on 32bit devices, and 64bit on 64bit devices. In any case I don't see any reason that you are getting this strange result, As in worst case you will have data lost, but not getting null at all.